# What's the best approach in iPhone UI customization?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating an iPhone app that uses the standard UI components... I would like to customize textures & buttons, but I'm not sure which is the best approach...

Should I make my component customization **while developing** or **after the app is ready and functional**??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always do after the app is completely functional. Once you've tested a working prototype, you can decide if you want to have swipes or touches instead of buttons for example. This way, you don't customize a button and decide it should be a different UI Element.

However, I do think you should customize UITableViewCells as you work, maybe not with gradients and custom graphics out of the gate, but certainly if you want a non-standard tableViewCell you should design that from the start.

Hope this is helpful